# Meteor gets WebSocket error with Apache Proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, meteor, proxy, ddp

I have a Meteor app that I access through an Apache proxy. The app seems to work but I see an error in the Chrome console. I guess it works because there is some less than ideal fallback. It gets the error:

```
ddp-client failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I've read lots of solutions to this problem which seems to be quite widespread (and tried quite a few) but they are often tied to complexities that make the solutions unusable in my very simple setup. Simply put, how should I configure my Apache proxy to serve Meteor and avoid the WebSocket ddp-client error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  my-domain.com

    ????

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is working because Meteor fallbacks to XHR long polling using SockJS behind the scenes.

To enable WebSocket proxying, if you are using Apache 2.4.5 and above, you can try using `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_wstunnel` (assuming your Meteor app listens on port 3000):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  my-domain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Without using the mentioned modules, you could try the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  my-domain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
</VirtualHost>
```